# Changing a simple src with Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have this piece of code:

```
function loadXMLDoc(h)
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        var getEle = document.getElementsByClassName('cut_oak_tree')[0];
            getEle.innerHTML = getEle.innerHTML.replace(h,xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","i",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

What this function does, is that when you press on an image, the image disappears. I want it to change to another image, and I have tried things like:

```
getEle.innerHTML = getEle.innerHTML.replace(h,xmlhttp.src="hello.png");
```

With no luck. The page contains several images of same type. if you like to see the html code, have a look:

```
<div class="cut_oak_tree">
            <img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png" onclick="loadXMLDoc(this.outerHTML), myFunction(this)" /> <!--DO NOT CHANGE SRC -->
            <br>
            <img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png " onclick="loadXMLDoc(this.outerHTML), myFunction(this)" /> <!--DO NOT CHANGE SRC -->
            <img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png  " onclick="loadXMLDoc(this.outerHTML), myFunction(this)" /> <!--DO NOT CHANGE SRC -->
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
getEle.innerHTML = getEle.innerHTML.replace(h,xmlhttp.responseText);
```

with this:

```
var imgElems = getEle.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgElems.length; i++) {
    imgElems[i].src = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

You might want to define a path for images, so you can use `imgElems[i].src = imagePath + xmlhttp.responseText;`.

UPDATE

So, change the img tags to this (loadXMLDoc parameter is changed):

```
<img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png" onclick="loadXMLDoc(this), myFunction(this)" />
```

Then, instead of the 4-line part I gave you above, use just this:

```
h.src = xmlhttp.responseText; // h now refers to the clicked image
```

Comment: Uhm, the images that are already there is not removed now. Nothing happens when the image is clicked on.

Comment: Sorry, thought the class name is the image itself, not the parent... I'll fix it now

Comment: This works except for the fact that it now replaces all images with that src and not just the one you pressed on. :)

Comment: Your original code was designed to do so :) Let me write another fix.

Comment: oh but if you notice the "src" in my html, it has small spaces which makes a difference to the src and hence it knows what image is clicked. Lol

Comment: uh, i'm lost now. What do I add and what do I not?

Comment: Haha, I don't think those spaces in the url were the best idea! :D  No problem, I'm glad I could help, sorry if it wasn't very clear from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You new new image wont load automatically, even if the path is correct

You can force the browser to reload the image by passing an extra variable like so:

```
 d = new Date();
 getEle.src = "xmlhttp.responseText?"+d.getTime();
```

Comment: The new source won't be applied simply because div elements can't have a source, no matter how many timestamps you put on them.